# Custom events in android

Tags: android, listview

I have a working android app. In this app I have an activity which displays transactions from SqlServer in a ListView, I've used ListViewAdapter (extends BaseAdapter) and net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver to display these Transactions, now I have added a Button to each row in the ListView and I want to delete the transaction from the server whenever user taps on the Button. I don't know where to start.

TransactionActivity.java

```
public class TransactionActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements   OnClickListener {

private EditText tranDate;
private DatePickerDialog dtpDialog;
private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat;
private ListView lvTransactions;
private Button btnAddNewTransaction;
private TransactionsListViewAdapter adapter;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> transactionsList;
private Date selectedDate;
private SqlDatabaseHelper sqldb = new SqlDatabaseHelper(this);
private DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_transaction);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);

    tranDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tranDate);
    tranDate.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
    tranDate.requestFocus();

    setDateTimeField();

    lvTransactions = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvTransactions);
    transactionsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    tranDate.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            refreshTransactions();
        }
    });
}

private void refreshTransactions() {
    transactionsList.clear();
    HashMap<String, String> headerRow = new HashMap<String, String>();
    headerRow.put(FIRST_COLUMN, "Party");
    headerRow.put(SECOND_COLUMN, "Type");
    headerRow.put(THIRD_COLUMN, "Amount");
    headerRow.put(FOURTH_COLUMN, "Status");
    transactionsList.add(headerRow);
    List<Transaction> tranList = sqldb.getTransactionsByDate(selectedDate);
    for (Transaction t : tranList) {
        HashMap<String, String> tranRow = new HashMap<String, String>();
        tranRow.put(FIRST_COLUMN, t.get_party().getName());
        String tTypeStr;
        int tType = t.get_transactionType();
        switch (tType) {
            case 0:
                tTypeStr = "आया";
                break;
            case 1:
                tTypeStr = "दिया";
                break;
            case 2:
                tTypeStr = "जमा";
                break;
            case 3:
                tTypeStr = "नामे";
                break;
            default:
                tTypeStr = "";
        }
        int tStat = t.get_transactionStatus();
        String tStatStr = "";
        switch (tStat) {
            case 0:
                tStatStr = "Fresh";
                break;
            case 1:
                tStatStr = "Synced";
                break;
            case 2:
                tStatStr = "Deleted";
                break;
        }
        tranRow.put(SECOND_COLUMN, tTypeStr);
        tranRow.put(THIRD_COLUMN, df.format(t.get_amount()));
        tranRow.put(FOURTH_COLUMN, tStatStr);
        transactionsList.add(tranRow);
    }
    adapter = new TransactionsListViewAdapter(this, transactionsList);
    lvTransactions.setAdapter(adapter);
    lvTransactions.invalidateViews();
}

private void setDateTimeField() {
    tranDate.setOnClickListener(this);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    dtpDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
            newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
            selectedDate = newDate.getTime();
            tranDate.setText(dateFormat.format(newDate.getTime()));
        }
    }, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
}


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view == tranDate) {
        dtpDialog.show();
    }
}
```

}

TransactionListViewAdapter.java

```
public class TransactionsListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;
Activity activity;
TextView txtFirst;
TextView txtSecond;
TextView txtThird;
TextView txtFourth;
Button btnDeleteTran;


public TransactionsListViewAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list) {
    super();
    this.activity = activity;
    this.list = list;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
    View view = null;
    convertView = null;
    if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.transaction_list_layout, null);

        txtFirst = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtTranParty);
        txtSecond = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtTranType);
        txtThird = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtTranAmount);
        txtFourth = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtTranStatus);
        btnDeleteTran = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnTranDelete);


        convertView.setTag(R.id.txtTranParty, txtFirst);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.txtTranType, txtSecond);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.txtTranAmount, txtThird);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.txtTranStatus, txtFourth);
        convertView.setTag(R.id.btnTranDelete, btnDeleteTran);

    }/* else {
        txtFirst = (TextView) convertView.getTag(R.id.Party);
        txtSecond = (TextView) convertView.getTag(R.id.Opponent1);
        txtThird = (TextView) convertView.getTag(R.id.Opponent2);
        txtFourth = (TextView) convertView.getTag(R.id.Draw);
    }*/

    HashMap<String, String> map = list.get(position);
    txtFirst.setText(map.get(FIRST_COLUMN));
    txtSecond.setText(map.get(SECOND_COLUMN));
    txtThird.setText(map.get(THIRD_COLUMN));
    txtFourth.setText(map.get(FOURTH_COLUMN));

    if (txtFirst.getText().equals("Party")) {
        btnDeleteTran.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    btnDeleteTran.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
```

}

Comment: What is your actual question? "I don't know where to start" is too vague and is basically asking to be spoon-fed.

Comment: Override the `clickevent` of the button and delete the selected item. That is all we can say without any code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Adapter just add an onclick listener for the button and place the code to delete the entry inside the listener. It may look like:

```
yourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
      public void onClick(View v){
         //deletion code here
      }
)};
```

where yourButton is the button to be clicked.
You should add this code in the `getView` method of the adapter

Comment: Thanks, but how to pass the transaction's unique id (UID) to this method.

Comment: you should pass the UID in the HashMap in the ArrayList along with other transaction details. If you already have passed it then access the UID field from the Hashmap with the position variable of the getView method

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I've done it. The transaction is being deleted from the server but this is done in the ListViewAdapter and how I refresh the ListView itself because that code is in TransactionActivity.

Comment: try calling notifyDataSetChanged() after removing the entry